# Python: discord.py: Error: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Trying to install discord.py and it keeps giving me an error. Looked into some solutions provided to others such as upgrading pip, or being on python 3.8 but none of it had any affect.

I'm not completely sure what I'm doing, just trying some things out and seeing if I can run a python script off a web server.

Any help is appreciated.

```
(KnishBot:3.8)[davajfzk@server228 KnishBot]$ python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (786 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-5.1.0.tar.gz (53 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in /home/davajfzk/virtualenv/KnishBot/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.0.0)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.6.3.tar.gz (176 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /home/davajfzk/virtualenv/KnishBot/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (21.2.0)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict, yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/davajfzk/virtualenv/KnishBot/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin /home/davajfzk/virtualenv/KnishBot/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp4r_qnufl
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_7jk_jgd/multidict_da04444149454b95bd2023db60177c47
  Complete output (44 lines):
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_multidict_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_abc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_multidict_py.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_multidict.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/dict.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/istr.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/iter.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/pair_list.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/views.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict
  /usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c multidict/_multidict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/multidict/_multidict.o -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing -pedantic
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/davajfzk/virtualenv/KnishBot/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin /home/davajfzk/virtualenv/KnishBot/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpod__ssr3
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_7jk_jgd/yarl_546a965bd0ae45cb80303d9a32ba7502
  Complete output (39 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_url.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_py.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_c.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl
  /usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c yarl/_quoting_c.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/yarl/_quoting_c.o
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński It's a Linux system.

Comment: ALready guessed that:), there's tons of different linux distributions, what distro exactly?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Apache server

Comment: That's not a linux distribution (nor an OS). I'm asking for the operating system, some examples of linux distributions -- ubuntu, debian, alpine...

Comment: That's all the information I'm given by my provider.

Comment: The issue is that `yarl` (a dependency of a dependency of discord.py) needs the `gcc` compiler which is absent on your machine. I'm asking for your operating system since the commands to install `gcc` vary a lot from distro to distro.

Comment: Linux-2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.67.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5

Comment: That's not a clear output, try with `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: 'cat: /etc/os-release: No such file or directory'

Comment: That’s really weird, what’s your provider?

Comment: I'm using Namecheap web hosting

Comment: why are you using a web host to host a discord bot?

Comment: As I said in my description, I'm just trying to see if it's possible.